# PHP Mailer Office 365

Tags: php, html, email, office365

I am just getting started in web development and I was tasked with creating a web-mail php form. I was able to pull a resource online and it works flawlessly with gmail, outlook.com and almost every other email service I throw at it, but when I add my office 365 account I never receive the message. I get an email from godaddy from an @a2plcpnl0560.prod.iad2.secureserver.net domain, but not on my office 365 email. I have been through the forums and I just don't have enough knowledge at the moment to know where to begin to tackle the problem. I have seen examples of PHPMailer being used and I attempted to make the code work but on my domain I never got the confirmation message from the form itself. I am not sure if there is something I  need to configure in the admin center of office 365 to get this to work or not. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "info@office365.com";
    $email_subject = "Inquiry";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||        !isset($_POST['email']) ||        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }


    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }


    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }


    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    ?>
```

Your request has been submitted, someone will be in contact with you shortly!

Comment: Please consider using phpmailer.

Comment: Also, the good people at `info@dot.swiss` will be unhappy that you throw away their e-mail address as invalid. It's not 2001 anymore, you want `filter_var($email_from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, or something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/201447/19746

Comment: This is all new to me, I have no background in PHP that script is something that I pulled from the web, if I am not mistaken you are talking about  $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';